# Blacklist .git folder in R CMD check

Tags: git, r

I'm pretty sure that a lot of you guys out there are using `git` as CVS. How do you bypass the following warning on `R CMD check`:

```
* checking for executable files ... WARNING
Found the following executable file(s):
```

I tried by putting `.git` folder in `.Rbuildignore`, but with no luck.

I reckon that this one is trivial for all of you who are using Github to host R packages. Any ideas?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Yes, use `.Rbuildignore` and then build the `.tar.gz` *and then check the `.tar.gz`* and not the source directory.

Comment: I knew that it was a trivial (read: _stupid_) one after all. Thanks Dirk!

Comment: And please be patient, you'll get a check-mark in t - 8 minutes. =)

Comment: No, not really -- I asked the same thing once but the official answer is to *test the tar.gz* even though I (like you) prefer to test on the directory.  It would be easy to tell the check script to skip `.git/` but alas it hasn't happened.

Comment: Yeah, it's completely counter-intuitive. So let's roll up our sleeves and implement `.Rcheckignore` for that one... =)

Comment: Advantage of installing/checking the built package is that you never have to clean up compilation artefacts.

Comment: According to [§1.3.2](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-exts.html#Building-package-tarballs) of ["Writing R Extensions"](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-exts.html), git files, among others, are automatically excluded from `R CMD`-built tarballs.

Comment: Yes but that change is much more recent than the  original question here.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could find to get rid of these stupid messages from my builds is to just filter it out for now:
`R CMD check . |grep -v .git`

Comment: That's just wrong you are supposed to *check the `tar.gz` file* and not the directory.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel why is the `check` working fine otherwise when running it on the directory? Should it then not just fail if one tries to do this, instead of only sort of work..