# Should there be a 'package' subfolder in a github package repo

Tags: r, package, devtools

I developed a small R package using [devtools](https://github.com/hadley/devtools) and put it on github (https://github.com/paulhurleyuk/PaulHurleyMisc).  I created it with this structure

```
PaulHurleyMisc\
    R\
    data\
    man\
```

because its a git repository, there is also a .git folder in the root, and when I do R CMD Check R complains about executable files.

Should I have created a subfolder under the root for the package ?  I haven't tried installing from github using devtools, so what would devtools expect?

Comment: Add it to .Rbuildignore

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you'll get rid of the warnings/errors if you check by doing `R CMD build` first and then running `R CMD check` on the tarball (this is recommended practice: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Checking-packages ). I don't think you actually need to put `.git` etc. in `.Rbuildignore`, as R now automatically ignores .git, .svn etc. files: see [`utils.R` in the `tools` package](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/bfe73ecd848198cb9b68427cec7e70c40f96bd72/src/library/tools/R/utils.R#L522-L527) (this has been [true for a while](https://github.com/wch/r-source/commit/839de42075b1dbc72c08ffbf12484b3f4f3b4722#src/library/tools/R/utils.R))

As @hadley points out in comments below, `devtools` automatically follows this route (i.e. it builds the tarball and then checks it rather than checking the directory directly)

Also see: [Blacklist .git folder in R CMD check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8887516/blacklist-git-folder-in-r-cmd-check)

Comment: Thanks for that, I had missed .Rbuildignore which would have solved my initial issue, but it's good to know there's a better process to follow.

Answer (score 3):

Everything looks ok to me.  If you're getting complains when you use R CMD stuff you can easily tell R to ignore some stuff by adding the corresponding files/folders to the .Rbuildignore file

Comment: I think if you check by doing `R CMD build` first and then running `R CMD check` on the tarball (I think this is recommended practice, but I can't point you to a reference for that) it automatically ignores .git, .svn etc. files

Comment: @BenBolker and devtools does that for you